# How to set react state values from another state values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array of objects in state:

```
const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState([
{
  height: 45,
  label: "tv",
  placeholder: "555",
  name: "tv",
  maxWidth: 203,
  value: dataValues.tv,
  priority: 1
},
{
  height: 45,
  label: "radio",
  placeholder: "50%",
  name: "radio",
  maxWidth: 126,
  value: dataValues.radio,
  priority: 2
},
{
  height: 45,
  label: "instagram",
  placeholder: "60%",
  name: "instagram",
  maxWidth: 126,
  value: dataValues.instagram,
  priority: 3
}
]);
```

I need each state value to be updated when another state updates (when I click on **submit money** button each state value should update), but it is not updating.
you can check the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-butterfly-lr7tc)

any help please?

Comment: `onSubmitMoney()` calls `setApiData()` with hardcoded values, not values from your form fields. Is that intentional?

Comment: Generally speaking, you wouldn't want to do this. Your form fields don't look like they need to be stateful. Try not making them stateful, and see if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input elements have their value set based upon your `formFields` object. When you initially make the object, you use values from your `dataValues` object, and `dataValues` will automatically update based on your `apiData` object due to what you wrote in your `useEffect` hook, however you never actually wrote anything to update `formFields` itself.

The following code should make it work as is,

```
    const newFormFields = [...formFields];
    newFormFields[0].value = apiData.tv;
    newFormFields[1].value = apiData.radio;
    newFormFields[2].value = apiData.instagram;
    setFormFields(newFormFields);
```

However I'd strongly advise refactoring. It seems like you've got a whole lot of needless redundancy here.

You mentioned in a comment that can't use indexes. In that case, something like this should work.

```
    const newFormFields = [...formFields];
    newFormFields.map(field => (field.value = apiData[field.name]));
    setFormFields(newFormFields);
```

Comment: Agreed. Generally the only things that should be in state are values that change (that are not props). The majority of your data is static.

Comment: thank you @Michael, but I can't use array index (newFormFields[0]) because on Drag and Drop fields the index is changing

Comment: I've added a sample that doesn't use indexes.